# Zope / Plone 3 product uninstsall issue

Tags: content-type, plone, zope

Hey all, I uninstalled a content type that I'd previously added and afterward I'm still getting a warning of

```
2010-01-06 22:43:50 WARNING OFS.Uninstalled Could not import class 'myclass
```

' from module 'ns.archetype_name.content.content_type_name'

It isn't resulting in obvious problems, but it concerns me since I thought I'd uninstalled it properly, and cannot find any place where I left a trace of it.  I've restarted the server, re-run buildout, and everything else I can think to try to get rid of that message, to no avail.

I read online that this warning is an indication that the Data.fs is out of sync with the packages, in question, and that I should re-install the missing packages.  I did that, and the error went away, but I'd really like to get rid of both the error *and* the content type in question.

Thanks!
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that the issue here was that there was content of that type on the portal; and so uninstalling hte package basically 'orphaned' those items, causing that error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

- Uninstall, remove, buildout.
- Go to ZMI at the zope root, Control
  Panel, Products. See if the the
  product is listed. Remove it.
- Restart.

This will likely make the annoyance disappear and if the product was providing simple content types should be enough. However you should check for funky left-overs such as persistent utils.

A good tool to help you find out what's going on if you still run into trouble is [zodbupdate](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zodbupdate). IIRC the latest version will only run on python 2.6, you should use the earlier ones.